# Get streaming output, error, allow user input with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.6

I am trying to run a shell command thru python and get its output, error message and allow the user to input yes/no when asked.

The command I and testing this with is

```
cp dummy dummy2 -i
```

Ideally I need a pythonic and up-to-date (python3.6) way that doesn't require additional software or libraries to be installed.

Bellow are some of my attempts:

```
# input  yes
# output no
# error  no
os.system(cmd)
```

.

```
# input  yes
# output no
# error  no
try:
    subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The code above seems to be the recomended way from the docs, but when stdout and stderr are set input does not work anymore. More specifically the program will wait for my input but not print the text asking me for my input.

```
# input  no
# output yes
# error  yes
try:
    p = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE ,check=True, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    print(p.stdout)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.stderr)
```

Using Popen should be more flexible, but if I set stderr I have the same problem as before.

```
# input  yes
# output yes
# error  no
process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
    bufsize=1,
    universal_newlines=True)
out, err = process.communicate()
print('out: ')
print(out)
print('err: ')
print(err)
```

The program waits for my input but does not show anything until I press enter.

```
# input  no
# output yes
# error  yes
process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
    bufsize=1,
    universal_newlines=True)
out, err = process.communicate()
print('out: ')
print(out)
print('err: ')
print(err)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? WHy do you want to capture `stdout`and `stderr`?

Comment: I am writing a program that deals with the errors if they exist so I need to parse `stderr`. The user also needs to answer some yes/no questions in the child command.